# Best brand of scale for kittens?

Tags: cats, fostering

I am fostering young kittens, and I am going to go buy a scale to weigh them. I looked at a few, but I can't decide which scale is best. Do any of you have a preferred scale, and what brand is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any digital scale is fine, we use baby scales but they are generally expensive.

If you are only weighing small kittens a digital kitchen scale works great, put kittens in a bowl and weigh.